# kafka console consumer pretty print json

Tags: json, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, pretty-print

How to print response from Kafka console consumer to JSON pretty. I have tried this but it's not working.

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic indexing-v1 
--from-beginning | python -m json.tool
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [jq](https://pypi.org/project/jq/) was able to view pretty JSON. Thanks.

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic indexing-v1 
--from-beginning  | jq
```

Comment: it working for curl response but for what reason; not for Kafka consumer.